# UISearchController does not retrieve the user when I am typing

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, uisearchcontroller

I want to search for first and last name from PFUser class using swift and Parse to follow and unfollow users. I used UISearchController, but it does not retrieve the user when I am typing. It just retrieved the users when Im pressing enter. 
another issue, when I searched for a user, it just retrieved first name not the last name. for example, when I search for Sara John, it retrieved Sara John and Sara March. however, when I typed M, it retrieved Sara March too. The problem is the first and last name together are not retrieved! how can I fix that?

Here is my code, I don't know what Im doing wrong, please help.

```
  func loadSearchUsers(searchString: String) {


    let firstName = searchString
    let lastName = searchString

    let firstNameQuery:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    firstNameQuery.whereKey("first_name", matchesRegex: "(?i)\(firstName)")

    let lastNameQuery:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    lastNameQuery.whereKey("last_name", matchesRegex: "(?i)\(lastName)")

    let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([firstNameQuery, lastNameQuery])

    self.searchActive = true

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
       //1
        if let users = objects {

        if (error != nil)
        {
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Error", message:error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction (title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
            myAlert.addAction(okAction)
            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return
        }
            self.searchUsers.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            self.userIds.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            self.isFollowing.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
           //2
            for object in users {
               //3
                if let user = object as? PFUser {
                //4
                if user.objectId! != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                    self.searchUsers.append(user)

                    self.userIds.append(user.objectId!)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    let query = PFQuery(className: "followers")
                    query.whereKey("followFrom", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
                    query.whereKey("followTo", equalTo: user.objectId!)
                    query.whereKey("status", equalTo:"followed")

                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                        if let objects = objects {

                            if objects.count > 0 {

                                self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = true

                            } else {

                                self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = false

                            }
                        }

                        if self.isFollowing.count == self.userIds.count {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            self.searchActive = false
                           }

                        })

            }
        }}
      }
    }
}

// MARK: - Search Bar Delegate Methods

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    let searchString: String = searchBar.text!.lowercaseString

        // Force search if user pushes button
    if (searchString != "") {
        loadSearchUsers(searchString)
    }else
    {loadSearchUsers("")}

    self.userSearchController.resignFirstResponder()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {


    searchActive = false
    searchBar.text = ""
    self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
        }

   func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController:   UISearchController) {
   let searchString = String()
            if       searchString.lowercaseString.containsString(self.userSearchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString) {
           if (searchString != "" && !self.searchActive) {
            loadSearchUsers(searchString)
           }
     //Updates the results tableview
      self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()

 }
}
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true
    self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method below for searching while you are writing simultaneously

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
```

Comment: Do you know how to retrieved two words together?

Comment: What about if I want to delete the search results when I delete what I typed?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to simplify your search query by a] using an NSPredicate, and, b] consolidating into 1 query.

```
// Pseudo code - you will need to pad this out with all the Parse fripperies
let searchKey = "Sara"
let pre = NSPredicate(format: "first_name CONTAINS %@ OR last_name CONTAINS %@", argumentArray: [search_key, search_key])
let qry = PFQuery(className: "User", predicate: pre)
```

You will need to adjust this code to fit how you are calling your query - in background or against pinned local data.  But I think this will help you.

Here is a link to the Parse guide on how to use Predicates - I highly recommend using them.  https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-specifying-constraints-with-nspredicate

**REMEMBER - Parse queries are case sensitive.**  This means if your stored value = "Sara" then searching for "sara" will fail.  It is often best to add a hidden column that contains text values in lowercase - and then use this column for searching.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will try that.

Comment: I couldn't used Predicates with PFUser :(